# Printing floating-point numbers with

Tags: perl

I have the following "help" subroutine:

```
sub help {

print <<HELP;

   useage:  the script will apply a constant set of changes on the code files

   Flags:
   -dest:   The output directory, 
   -source: The path to the directory where the source code is. 
   -ver:    The version of the code (default = $version)

HELP
    exit 0;
}
```

The variable `$version` is set to `3.0`, but when I call the subroutine, it only prints:

```
   -ver:                     The version of the code (default = 3)
```

i.e., it does not print the dot and the zero.

How can I fix this?

Comment: BTW, one of Perl's conventions is that version numbers are stored in `$VERSION`, as in: `our $VERSION = '3.0';`

Answer (score 2):

Either specify the version as a string:

```
my $version = "3.0";
```

Or use `printf` to specify the precision when printing the numeric value.

```
printf ( "%.1f", $version );
```

Or if you really want to get funky about it, make `$version` a dualvar, that gives different values in string and number context. (This is showing off - it's probably a bad idea for maintainable code).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Scalar::Util qw ( dualvar );

my $version = dualvar ( 3.0,  "three point zero" );

print $version,"\n";
if ( $version >= 3.0 ) { print "3.0 or higher\n" };
```

If you specify a scalar a value as numeric, perl turns it into a number. `3.0 = 3.00 = 3` and so it'll print with the minimum precision necessary by default. That's why you have this problem.

You may find it useful to look at [`version`](http://search.cpan.org/~jpeacock/version-0.9912/lib/version.pod) too.

Answer (score 2):

Use [printf](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc):

```
sub help {
    printf(<<HELP, $version);
usage:  the script will apply a constant set of changes on the code files

Flags:
   -dest:   The output directory,
   -source: The path to the directory where the source code is.
   -ver:    The version of the code (default = %.1f)
HELP
    exit 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Usage:  the script will apply a constant set of changes on the code files

Flags:
   -dest:   The output directory,
   -source: The path to the directory where the source code is.
   -ver:    The version of the code (default = 3.0)
```